# Not redirecting to the external URL without var_dump() Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-5.1

Laravel is not redirecting to an returned external url.

```
public function main ($status,$projectid,$respid,$country) {
    //Store the passed-in URL parameters to private properties
    $this->status = $status;
    $this->projectid = $projectid;
    $this->respid = $respid;
    $this->country = $country;

    //Run the starting function
    if ($this->verifyId()) {
        $this->getLinks();
        $this->storeData();
        $this->prjUpdate();
        $this->redirect();
    }
}

public function redirect () {
    //Redirect to the set redirect links
    if ($this->status === "Complete")
    {
        return redirect()->away('http://google.com', 302);
    } elseif ($this->status === "Incomplete")
    {
        return redirect()->away('http://google.com');
    } elseif ($this->status === "Quotafull")
    {
        return redirect()->away('http://google.com');
    }
}
```

The `$this->redirect()` is not redirecting to the set URL `return redirect()->away('http://google.com', 302);` but when I do `var_dump($this->redirect());` it works. If `var_dump()` is removed it doesn't redirect.

Comment: BTW show the example where u are using "main" method

Comment: Here `Route::get('/{status}/{projectid}/{respid}/{country}', 'RespDataController@main');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace

```
//Run the starting function
if ($this->verifyId()) {
    $this->getLinks();
    $this->storeData();
    $this->prjUpdate();
    $this->redirect();
}
```

with

```
//Run the starting function
if ($this->verifyId()) {
    $this->getLinks();
    $this->storeData();
    $this->prjUpdate();
    return $this->redirect();
}
```

Comment: Ow thanks a ton.. Finally its working.. I was under the impression that I'm actually returning the `$this->redirect();` value to the route controller.